# Is there a way to capture HotKeys/Shortcuts in Excel VSTO using only C# and no VBA?

Tags: excel, .net-3.5, vsto, excel-2007, hotkeys

So I want to capture some key-commands in our Docuement-level Excel VSTO addin. I can't seem to find a way to do it, other than to use VBA and have our addin talk to the VBA. Any help/examples would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: The Visual Studio Office Development (VSOD) Support Team has written an article about this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2010/04/08/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this through API calls to subclass Excel and watch for key commands. [This](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vs-net-office/701/Capture-Keystrokes-CTRL-SOMETHING) is older, but it still applies.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 4):

1. One method involves using the 3rd party solution from **Addin-Express**. Their product includes the ability to add a keyboard shortcut as a property to the ribbon menu commands.
2. The other way is to make use of low level keyboard hooks, through some **Win32 API's** which is generally referred to as *windows subclassing*. Here is an excellent explanation with code sample of how to do it. Note that the only "extra" thing you need to do to get this code to "work" in VSTO is moving the `SetHook()` method to the `Startup` event, and the UnhookWindowsHookEx() method to the Shutdown event.

[Check out the article on MSDN here by Stephen Toub.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217145327/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx)

3. Finally there is the use of the `OnAction` property of the Addin class. This method requires the use of some VBA (*in terms of a callback method that points back to the underlying .net addin*), and works ok so long as you are willing to distribute some VBA in your solution (*i.e. a xls or doc w/ vba project, or perhaps a native addin*). Note you will also need to mark `comvisible = true`, and expose the `GetAutomationServiceObject` method so that your VBA can reference your addin from VBA code.

[see here for a thread on it...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6265bb47-1b66-4173-9892-fa4515a6cb80/shortcut-key-for-excel-addin?forum=vsto)

Comment: Looks like the Geoff Darst link now longer works.  Any idea where to find that article now?  Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft See this link from narkive : http://microsoft.public.vsnet.vstools.office.narkive.com/a5kXwA4E/capture-keystrokes-ctrl-something