# register Shortcut-Key only for Excel VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, keyboard-shortcuts, excel-addins

In my VSTO project (*for Excel*) I want to hook a shortcut-Key (*keyboard combination of 3 keys*) to a function in my C# code.
for example when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> a function `MyShortCutFuction` should invoked.

Comment: The Visual Studio Office Development (VSOD) Support Team has written an article about this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2010/04/08/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [expose your VSTO assembly to COM so that it is callable from a VBA Macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386306.aspx) (***ComVisible***). This requires several manual steps, but [once you've accessed the assembly from COM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pstubbs/archive/2004/12/31/344964.aspx), you can assign [**Macro Shortcut Keys**](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s139/short-cut-key-macros-excel.htm).

Another possibility is directly hooking into the [Win32 API for tracking keyboard events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) (***windows subclassing***). [Here is a reference implementation using `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`](https://gist.github.com/471698) Win32 API.

Also see [related SO post regarding keyboard capture approaches in VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2909302/175679).